# Imaginary eigenvalue after real rank one update.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ with complex eigenvalues $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{C}$ with non-zero imaginary parts.

Can we bound the change of the imaginary part of $\lambda_i$ after a rank one update $W+uv^T$ for $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

What if the update is $W+2\frac{Wxx^TW}{||Wx||^2}$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Rosenbrock's pole assignment theorem implies that, for "almost any" choice of $W$ and suitably selected $u,v$, the eigenvalues update can be steered to any desired set of eigenvalues (that come in complex-conjugate pairs)

Comment: We can bound the eigenvalues a bit better in the case that $W$ is symmetric, per Weyl's inequalities.

Comment: Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* has a theorem (VIII.1.1) that leads to the following bound to the change in the eigenvalue: 
$$
\Delta \lambda_i \leq (\|W\| + \|W + uv^T\|)^{1 - 1/n}\cdot (\|u\|\cdot\|v\|)^{1/n},
$$
where $\|W\|$ denotes the spectral norm (maximal singular value) of $W$. Note that we can rewrite $\|W + uv^T\| \leq \|W\| + \|uv^T\| = \|W\| + \|u\|\cdot \|v\|$ to simplify the expression a bit.